# How do I ignore the assets folder when uploading Android project to github?

Tags: android, github

I'm trying to upload my android project to github, but the assets is too large > 300mb.
What is the correct way to place the assets path inside the `.gitignore` file? Inside the gitignore it currently looks like this, but after trying to upload it to github, it didnt work so I'm assuming it's incorrect:

```
/build
/.app/src/main/assets
```

This is the path of the `.gitignore`

```
-DesktopFolder
    -app
       -src
          -main
             -assets
             -java
             -res
       .gitignore
```

[image]

Edit:

I have also  tried

`/app/src/main/assets`

and

`/src/main/assets`

but neither work

Edit 2:

I've also tried creating a `.gitignore` file inside the assets folder with a asterisk `*` but that doesn't work either.

Edit 3:

Pushing the project to github:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git remote add origin <project url>
git push -f origin master
```

I have also tried `git rm -rf --cached .`

Comment: Why is there a `.` before `app`?

Comment: Are your assets already pushed to the server?

Comment: @user3840170 I've removed it.

Comment: @JoãoPauloSena  No they are not because the upload fails everytime

Comment: @DIRTYDAVE: It’s still there.

Comment: In my edits I have already tried it without the ```.```

Comment: Did you successfully git commit, not push, just commit the assets into the repo?

Comment: Yes, I added what I tried in Edit3 above. It's still uploading all the assets

Comment: Also, if you commit them, are the commits too far away from the HEAD or are they literally the last commit?

Comment: Did you add and commit it to your VCS? or no?

Comment: Should the rows in your `.gitignore` be relative and not absolute paths? e.g. `./src/main/assets/*`

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you didn't push the contents to the online Source Control yet.

In this case you need to identify the commit that introduced the files/folders you are trying to remove.

I created an example. I don't know if you are using any UI for git, so, I'll stick with the git command line.

When I run `git log` on the repo I have this output:
[image: I Added a huge file in this commit]

I know that the commit `7620899...` is the one that added the huge file to the repo, since I don't want it there, I'll undo the commit, add the files to the gitignore and commit everthing again.

In my case, the `7620899...` commit is the last one in the tree, so, I just need to run `git reset HEAD~1` where `1` here means the amount of commits I'd like to undo.

After that, I add the huge file to .gitignore and save the file.
[image: Added huge folder to gitignore]

When I check `git status` I see that the huge_file.mp4 is no longer showing in my working directory, just the change at gitignore
[image: Nothing in working dir]

Now, I can finally `git add .` and `git commit -m "A commit message"`

This should remove the assets from your repo, be aware that in my example, I only went back 1 commit, if you need to go back more than one change the HEAD~N where N is the commit count you want to go back. If you want to keep the commits and just remove the files while rewriting git history, you might need to use `git rebase`.